I'm trying to mount mysql backup file using kubectl, but it was saved as a directory, not a file
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-dump-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /local/mysql
  storageClassName: local-storage  # using local-storage StorageClass


---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-dump-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  storageClassName: local-storage  # using local-storage StorageClass


---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mysql
          image: mysql:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: MY_PASSWORD
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysql-dump-volume
              mountPath: /tmp/dump
      volumes:
        - hostPath:
            path: /local/mysql
          name: mysql-dump-volume
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: role
                operator: In
                values:
                - backend

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306

It is Mysql setting yaml file. I'm trying to mount '/local/mysql/backup.sql' to the directory '/tmp/dump' in mysql pod, but it was saved as a directory.
inner pod
The file 'backup.sql' is saved as a directory. If you think there's a problem with my setup file, please let me know.
chmod +x backup.sql

I have authorized it through this command.
initContainers:
        - name: init-mysql
          image: busybox
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p /tmp/dump/ && cp -r /local/mysql/* /tmp/dump/']
          volumeMounts:
            - name: host-volume
              mountPath: /local/mysql
            - name: mysql-dump-volume
              mountPath: /tmp/dump

And I alse initialized pod by this part.
Is there anything else I need to add or fix?

How are you getting the file on to the Node where the Pod will eventually be running?  How do you know which Node it is?  Can you kubectl port-forward a connection to the database and run the restore over that, without trying to use volumes?

@DavidMaze It's been resolved by using kubectl port-forward method without using PV.
